# Ajax in ASP.NET MVC3 Razor

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem with Ajax.
I want to make multiple forms and replace div containing one after submiting with some Partial View. It's working for me when I use only one form. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Maybe it's becasue of custom editorfor?
Here is my code, plese try to help me, I've been trying do this for 2 days.

**Index**

```
@model MetriceWeb.Models.TaskInputModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Tasks";
}
<h3>
    Tasks</h3>

@if (Model.Values.Count == 0)
{
   <p>No pendings forms for you at the moment</p>
}
else
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Values)
}
```

**TaskInputValue (editorfor)**

```
@model MetriceWeb.Models.TaskInputValue
@{string s = "task" + Model.TaskId;}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetFromLibrary", "Metrice", new AjaxOptions
{
HttpMethod = "Get",
UpdateTargetId = s,
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
}))
{
<div class="editor-field" id="@s">
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TaskId, new { @class = "TaskId" , id = "TaskId" })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.InputId, new { @class = "InputId" })
<h2>
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Task)
</h2>
<span>Created: </span>
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Date)

<div>
Input Value

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.DateValue)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DateValue)
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</div>
<br />
}
```

It's entering method in my controller where I'm returning partial view. After submitting my div isn't replacing, the whole new site is loaded. What is wrong here? Please help me, I am in big need.

Comment: Please check that the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is referenced in loaded for your page! Can you also post your controller method?

Comment: Oh my God. I'm really stupid sometimes. I hadn't included this reference. Thank you and I'm sorry i took your time with my stupid problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to the `Ajax` helpers like `Ajax.BeginForm` work correctly (e.g sending an AJAX request) you need reference in your view the following JavaScript file

```
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
```

(and of course before that jquery)

From the [Unobtrusive Ajax in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-ajax.html)

> An interesting note: since there is no actual JavaScript being emitted
>   when you use unobtrusive Ajax, if you forget to include one or the
>   other script, you won’t see any errors when attempting to submit the
>   Ajax request; it will simply behave like a non-Ajax request.